# BoxLayout adding left margin

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, layout-manager, boxlayout

I've got a JPanel that has a `BoxLayout` (Page axis), and I want to lay out two components, one on top of the other.

[image]

My problem is the margin to the left of the large lipsum box, how can I get rid of this? If I don't add the top components, there is no margin.

[image]

Here's my code, the second image is created by not adding `headerPanel`:

```
JLabel commandLabel = new JLabel(command);
    JLabel paramLabel = new JLabel(params);
    JLabel descLabel = new JLabel("<html><body style='width: 200px;'>" + description + "</body></html>");
    Font baseFont = commandLabel.getFont(), commandFont, paramFont, descFont;

    commandFont = baseFont.deriveFont(Font.BOLD);
    paramFont = baseFont.deriveFont(Font.ITALIC);
    descFont = baseFont.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN);

    commandLabel.setFont(commandFont);
    paramLabel.setFont(paramFont);
    descLabel.setFont(descFont);
    descLabel.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    descLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createStrokeBorder(new BasicStroke()));   
    JPanel headerPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
        headerPanel.add(commandLabel);
        headerPanel.add(paramLabel);
    this.add(headerPanel);
    this.add(descLabel);
```

This class extends `JPanel`, and is added to a `JFrame`, which is simply `pack()`'d

Comment: `Here's my code` - post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. We can't compile/execute the code provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I couldn't tell where the observed behaviour comes from, the expected display could be achieved by using an intermediate `JPanel` to contain your label, rather than adding the `JLabel` directly :

```
    JLabel commandLabel = new JLabel(command);
    JLabel paramLabel = new JLabel(params);
    JLabel descLabel = new JLabel("<html><body style='width: 200px;'>" + description + "</body></html>");
    Font baseFont = commandLabel.getFont(), commandFont, paramFont, descFont;

    commandFont = baseFont.deriveFont(Font.BOLD);
    paramFont = baseFont.deriveFont(Font.ITALIC);
    descFont = baseFont.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN);

    commandLabel.setFont(commandFont);
    paramLabel.setFont(paramFont);
    descLabel.setFont(descFont);
    descLabel.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    descLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createStrokeBorder(new BasicStroke()));   
    JPanel headerPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
    JPanel descPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));// added
    headerPanel.add(commandLabel);
    headerPanel.add(paramLabel);

    descPanel.add(descLabel);// added

    this.add(headerPanel);
    this.add(descPanel);// modified
```

Comment: I will try this, thanks (dev machine out of battery)

Answer (score 1):

> My problem is the margin to the left of the large lipsum box, how can I get rid of this?

You need to make the alignments of your components consistent. That is the alignment "X" property of all the components should be left aligned.

I'm guessing the `JLabel` is center aligned so you need to use:

```
descLabel.setAlignmentX(JLabel.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
```

See [Fixing Alignment Problems](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html#alignment) section from the Swing tutorial on `How to Use BoxLayout` for more information and examples.